# Maven not recognizing full file path

Tags: java, maven, path, filepath

So I have this in my pom:

```
<build>
<directory>${project.parent.basedir}\build</directory>
</build>
```

and it outputs this error: Cannot create resource output directory: C:\Users\theob\GitHub\Octane\Capes\C:\Users\theob\GitHub\Octane\build\classes

It works if I define the path manually (IE: C:/Users/theob/GitHub/Octane/build) but when I use a variable for it, it doesn't work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Remove parent out of path

Comment: @JAsgarov Hey, I am trying to put the build directory in the parent directory, not the base directory though.

Comment: Follow the conventions of Maven otherwise you start fighting against the conventions which makes life harder. The other question what is the purpose of changing that? And more interesting: Why?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using maven modules system and want to have it compile to the same directory so its easier to drag and drop (for testing), instead of having to navigate through a ton of separate target directories.

Comment: If you want testing you have either unit tests which are by module automatically executed or integration tests which usually should be done in a separate module.